# Can't Install EclipseCoder on Galileo

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

java version "1.8.0_45"

I can't Install [EclipseCoder](http://fornwall.net/eclipsecoder/) on my machine Mac OS X 10.10.3.

Its was woking fine but since last few days it crashed.So I uninstalled it and again tried to install but

Installation fails with the following error message

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: EclipseCoder Java Support 0.2.10 (net.fornwall.eclipsecoder.javasupport.feature.group 0.2.10)
>     Missing requirement: EclipseCoder Java Support 0.2.10 (net.fornwall.eclipsecoder.javasupport.feature.group 0.2.10) requires 'org.eclipse.jdt.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Try installing JDT first, not sure why it didn't get picked up automatically.

Comment: Installed JDT still the same error message.

Comment: :-( I don't have more ideas, Galileo is very old so perhaps a bug or two has been fixed since then. Have you tried Mars.1? (Galileo is 6 years old BTW and predates Java 8 by a couple of years)

Comment: It worked on Mars Thank you :)